# Why just getting 25 post?

Tags: wordpress, loops

I'm making a code to access to all post in wordpress, but I am just getting the last 25 posts and no more, this is the code

```
$args = array(      
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'homeland_properties',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

i need to get all posts but if i change the numberposts parameter for example to 25  work ok and get all result but if i put 26 just not work, and i dont understand why, and if i put -1 to get all posts same not work.
some help...

Comment: You're probably having default pagination coming into play, have you looked on the codex for pagination options? https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Posts_with_Previous_Next_Navigation

Comment: hi Lee, thanks for the answer, so i didn´t looked this pagination options that you mention, how can i do that and remove this limit of 25 posts?.          The thing is i am working with common post and i need to get all posts wish type is "homeland_properties" and get all information about it, wish information are, allmost, like 'meta-key', why that i will like to use just this way and not use the "WP_Query" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [wp_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) you can also complete this task try this

```
 <?php 
    // the query
    $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>

    <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <ul>

        <!-- the loop -->
        <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- end of the loop -->

    </ul>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi Hassan, thanks for the answer, as i comment before the thing is i am working with common post and i need to get all posts wish type is "homeland_properties" and get all information about it, wish information are, allmost, like 'meta-key', this way with WP_Query could be a option but i dont know how to access and get all the information about the post wish is save it like a 'meta-key', so how can i get it?. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try making a WP_Query

```
$new_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'homeland_properties',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    )
);
```

And then use this for the loop

```
while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post();
```

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for the answer, this can be a option, but how can i get all the information about the post, i post a comment before here asking the same, please read the answer before yours, meabe you can tell me how can i do that.

Comment: the_permalink() for the link the_title() for the title the_content() for the post content. Its just the standard wordpress functions for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I just solve the problem adding some more parameters to the array to filter a littel bit more the result, i dont know why making this filtering work, and without it not work, thinking a litel i can say if i add this filter to the array to get more specific posts meabe this pagination option disappear
 and get all posts that i want, in any case this is the code.

```
$args = array(      'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'my_custom_post',
        'meta_key'   => 'my_meta_key',
        'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
        );

$posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $posts as $post ) :   setup_postdata( $post );   // The Loop;                  endforeach;
```

thanks a lot to every one for your attention.